# Arabxetex plus missing glyph

Tags: fonts, symbols, arabic, arabxetex

The default font for `arabxetex` is Amiri. Here I want to use different font which is [Markazi Text](https://github.com/BornaIz/markazitext) together with `quran` package.

```
\documentclass[b5paper,11pt]{memoir}
\usepackage[left=1.8cm,right=1.8cm,top=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{arabxetex}
\usepackage[uthmani]{quran}

\begin{document}
\noindent
Amiri:
\medskip
\begin{arab}
\noindent\ToggleAyahNumber\quranayah[2][258]
\end{arab}

\medskip\medskip
\noindent
Markazi Text:
\medskip
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic]{Markazi Text}
\begin{arab}
\noindent\ToggleAyahNumber\quranayah[2][258]
\end{arab}

\end{document}
```

Output:
[image]

As you can see, some glyph is missing for the Markazi Text font. Is there a way to skip this glyph as if they weren't there?

Comment: That character is not insignificant. If you want something with a simpler appearance than Amiri, why not choose a font, such as Noto Naskh Arabic, that has the character?

Comment: If you had a font missing, say, 'e', would you try to typeset King James with that font, skipping all the 'e's?